# Talend - tmap - expression filter - how to filter against a list of values

Tags: list, filter, expression, talend, tmap

I have a list of values to filter against. Because the number and content in this list is dynamic, there is no way to work with a static query via .equals.

My current filter is hard coded:

row1.col1.equals("        3810")||row1.col1.equals("        3811")

[image: filter expression with .equals]

What I want to use is a more SQL like statement:

row1.col1 in (listOfValues) where ListOfValues could be given by a variable or a context. I can't find anything appropriate to filter against a list.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: the values 3810 , 3811 , etc .. are stored in a database , in a global variable , in a context ?   beacause your requirements needs to be passed by a Talend Routine i guess .

Comment: Yes, the values are from out of a database. I stored this comma separated list in a global variable for further use in the expression filter.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me:

I wrote a java helper class, that compares the input value from row1 with the list of valid values stored in a global variable. The string to be compared against first splitted and trimmed to get the single values in a list. A short check if the given input value from row1 is in this list I used the .contains method. The return value (boolean) will than be the criteria to filter or not.

```
public class FileTransferBranchFilter {


    public static boolean contains(String checkMCU, String lovMCU) {
        
        /* lovMCU = list of valid MCUs in comma separated format
         * this list has to be splitted in single values for comparison
         * lpad with blanks to 12 digits is necessary for comparison 
         * of the MCU to be checked with the filter list*/
        
        String[] result = lovMCU.trim().split("\\s*,\\s*");
        List<String> lov = Arrays.asList(result);
        checkMCU = checkMCU.trim();
        
        
        
    //  System.out.println("eine Liste der gültigen MCUs" + Arrays.toString(result));
    //  System.out.println("die zu überprüfende MCU: " + checkMCU);
        
        if(lov.contains(checkMCU)) {
            //System.out.println("die zu überprüfende MCU befindet sich somit in der Liste der gültigen MCUs --> " + checkMCU);
            return true;
        }else {
            //System.out.println("die zu überprüfende MCU befindet sich somit nicht in der Liste der gültigen MCUs --> " + checkMCU);
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

Here the expression in the expression builder:

[image]